# SQL Server: Getting last 7 months of data for month column that just contains integers 1-12?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, alteryx

I have a dataset in Alteryx that puts years and months into different columns of integers (ex. months: 1-12 and years: 2018) and I have been able to dynamically select the last year but cannot figure out how to dynamically receive only the last 7 months of data. I know I could combine the month and year and transform it into a datetime format to use DATEADD(), however, the rest of my workflow depends on them being seperate. Is there anyway to accomplish this with either SQL or in Alteryx?

EX:
current_month = 2 so it must return where sales_month = 1, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7

or

current_month = 12 so it must return where sales_month = 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5

Any guidance would be helpful,  have tried MANY different potential solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you splitting attributes like month and year? Would be a lot simpler if you had a date(time) datatype so you can just use simple date math.

Comment: Yes, it would be much simpler, but the way the data flows in is separate and the way its used for the rest  of the workflow is also separate and as ints. This is also not my workflow and, it would be simpler to solve this issue than to redo the rest of the flow, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

try like below for getting last 7 month number

```
  SELECT  MONTH(DATEADD(mm, -m, GETDATE())) AS m,
            LEFT(DATENAME(mm,  DATEADD(mm, -m, GETDATE())), 3) AS n,
            YEAR(DATEADD(mm, -m, GETDATE())) AS y
    FROM    (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)) t(m)


m   name    y
3   Mar 2019
2   Feb 2019
1   Jan 2019
12  Dec 2018
11  Nov 2018
10  Oct 2018
9   Sep 2018
8   Aug 2018
```

use this output as CTE and join with your table to get back last 7 month

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do comparisons like this:

```
where (@current_month >= 7 and sales_month > @current_month - 7) or
      (@current_month < 7 and
       (sales_month > 0 or
        sales_month > 12 - (@current_month - 7)
      )
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, at a minimum you're missing a parentheses. I assumed at the end, but maybe it works if placed in the middle somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [`DATETIMEFROMPARTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to do this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sales_month
FROM your_table
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS(sales_year,sales_month,1) BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH,-8,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND DATEADD(MONTH,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could construct a `DATE` in your `WHERE` clause using `DATEFROMPARTS`, then toss in an extra variable for your comparison date, just to avoid retyping it in the `WHERE` clause.

```
DECLARE @current_month INT = 1
       ,@current_year INT = 2019

DECLARE @compDate DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(@current_year,@current_month,DAY(GETDATE()))

SELECT
 *
FROM @t
WHERE 
 DATEFROMPARTS(current_year,current_month,DAY(GETDATE())) >= DATEADD(MONTH, -7, @compDate)
 AND
 DATEFROMPARTS(current_year,current_month,DAY(GETDATE())) < @compDate
```

Results:

```
+---------------+--------------+
| current_month | current_year |
+---------------+--------------+
|             6 |         2018 |
|             7 |         2018 |
|             8 |         2018 |
|             9 |         2018 |
|            10 |         2018 |
|            11 |         2018 |
|            12 |         2018 |
+---------------+--------------+
```

Here's the table set up for testing:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
  current_month INT NOT NULL,
  current_year INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT @t
  (
    current_month
   ,current_year
  )
VALUES
  (1, 2018),
  (2, 2018),
  (3, 2018),
  (4, 2018),
  (5, 2018),
  (6, 2018),
  (7, 2018),
  (8, 2018),
  (9, 2018),
  (10, 2018),
  (11, 2018),
  (12, 2018),
  (1, 2019),
  (2, 2019),
  (3, 2019);
```